# Ionic4 navController back with params (callback)

Tags: ionic4

Just looking for best practice for sending data from a child route, back up to its parent. For example, if I have a list view and I want to add an item which is complex enough to merit its own page, how do I get that added item back to the list view? Now obviously I could just re-fetch the entire list but that seems kind of silly and not efficient. I found that I can also pass a “callback function” in the ActivatedRoute params when router navigates the AddPage, but that also felt wrong (though I like it better than the first option). It’d be great if I could pass the data back through the nav.back() method, but what is the recommended way to do what I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you haven't provided any relevant code/attempt in your question, and that you are "looking for the beset practice" for sending data from a child route, this question looks too broad. Can you please provide an attempt or clear example?

Answer (score 1):

```
pass in a callback when transitioning(it is not working in ionic4)

 // callback...
 myCallbackFunction = function(_params) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             resolve();
         });
 }

 // push page...
this.navController.navigateForward(["add-product",{"callback": myCallbackFunction}]);

in the AddProductPage
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((data: any) => {
     this.callback = data.callback;
    console.log("callback "+this.callback)

});
error:-i m getting data in string form(here i m getting callback data in string format)
output:-
callback "function(_params) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             resolve();
         });
"
 this.callback(param).then(()=>{
    this.navController.pop();
 });
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Still looking for answer!

Comment: you can use :- that at HomePage.js 1.goback(){ const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {state : {data: dataObject}};
  this.navController.navigateBack('/menu', navigationExtras);} 2.at Menu Page use :- history.state.data(to get data);

Answer (score 0):

I do what Pradeep said, and its working:
Put navCtrl in your constructor parameter:

```
private navCtrl: NavController,
```

And somewhere in your code when you want to go back:

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        param: "1",
      }
    };
this.navCtrl.navigateBack(['previouspage'], navigationExtras)
```

In your previous page constructor:

```
constructor(
    ........
    private router: Router,
){
 if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state && this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.param) {
  let param = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.param
 }
}
```